# Problema confuguração de server para o laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache

[image: Fiz a migração do meu site para o server hostgator e não esta direcionado para a pasta public.Aguem sabe me dizer porque isso acontece?]

Fiz a migração do meu site para o server hostgator e não esta direcionado para a pasta public.Aguem sabe me dizer porque isso acontece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que configurar o seu servidor para considerar a pasta `public` como a raiz do web server. É preciso habilitar o `mod_rewrite` no Apache também.

Procure no painel do Hostgator a opção para [alterar a pasta inicial do projeto](https://medium.com/@rodneyneville/publicando-framework-laravel-5-1-no-hostgator-50a027157003).

Comment: Valeu pelo salve gmsantos ajudou muito.